# Trouble with alert and listening to a click event

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to have an alert when i click on an image. I am trying to select element by id. I have tried both querySelector and getElementbyId. If I set the event listener to the page load, an alert comes upon reload. 
so I am sure I am linking the page correctly, but I am doing something wrong when I try to listen to a click on the image.

I have tried both querySelector and getElementbyId. I have put the script in the head and in its own file. I have put the id on both the image tag and in a span and div around the image.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  alert("RELOAD");
});

let thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click",     function() {
  alert("I saw you click!");
});
```

```html
<div id="smart_thumbnail">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454789548928-9efd52dc4031?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80" alt="earth" class="small">
</div>
```

The error in the console in the browser is this:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: please, clarify your question because using the snippet I didn't see any errors

Comment: @CalvinNunes What browser are you using? I want to click on the image and have an alert.. as of now, in both firefox and chrome, this event listener is not woriking and when i click the image nothing happens, but in the console i get an error `TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null` or `TypeError: thumbnailElement is null`depending on how I write it

Comment: @CalvinNunes what is working is the on reload event. not a click. Ill change the message so that is clear

Comment: for me, the click is also working... I run the snippet, a mesage with "RELOAD" appears, then i click the image and an alert with "I Saw you click" appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you access the value of the DOM element you have to make sure the element exists already.

In case your scripts are running before your html loads, you can make it work by waiting for the window to finish loading first:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   alert("RELOAD");
   let thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

   thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("I saw you click!");
   });
});
```